Create an ELF file which resolves some symbols lazily and other symbols immediately
A dynamically linked ELF file resolves the symbols at runtime. Either it does so immediately at startup to resolve all symbols or they get lazily resolved whenever a symbol is actually being called.
I would like to create an executable which resolves one symbol lazily and another immediately on startup.
Is that possible giving arguments to the linker?
If not, what do I need to patch in the finished binary?
I can for example switch between both modes using LD_BIND_NOW. But only for all symbols at once.  I could force lazy binding and call all symbols I want to be resolved immediately at startup, but I want it to be the originally intended way the dynamic linker works to resolve symbols without having to call them.

http://xyproblem.info is likely relevant here.

Its mostly research and curiosity. So, no, its not a xy problem. An answer to this could be very useful for performance sensitive applications as symbol resolving has a non trivial performance impact. A fine grained control over it would be very helpful.


Either it does so immediately at startup to resolve all symbols or they get lazily resolved whenever a symbol is actually being called.

Yes, these are the only two choices.

I would like to create an executable which resolves one symbol lazily and another immediately on startup.

That is impossible to by either giving arguments to the linker or by patching the binary.

this could be very useful for performance sensitive applications as symbol resolving has a non trivial performance impact. A fine grained control over it would be very helpful.

I failed to see a use case where resolving some symbols immediately while postponing resolution of others is desirable.
People generally use immediate symbol resolution (LD_BIND_NOW) to avoid runtime surprises later (e.g. a called symbol turned out to not be available half way through program execution, resulting in the loader doing fatal exit), and are willing to pay startup delay for this safety.
You want to pay some of the cost for a particular set of symbols, but you gain none of the guarantees that come from doing the full symbol resolution.
So what benefit do you hope to derive from doing paying this smaller cost?
Update:

Look at it from a pure performance perspective (e.g. for embedded systems).

This still looks like an XY problem to me. Your arguments make no sense from performance perspective.

You know that some symbols are very rarely, or at all, used. You can make them load lazily and improve startup time.

Yes, this is the default (lazy binding).

You know that some symbols are critical to have and are used all the time. Make them load immediately.

Resolving these symbols immediately provides no appreciable benefit: if these symbols are used all the time, they will get resolved very soon after the program startup.
You are doing the same amount of work either way. Immediate resolution of these symbols just moves that work a little bit earlier in the process' lifetime.

You could (but didn't) argue that in an embedded system once you've started control loop, you need predictable performance, and therefore should avoid symbol resolution delays.
But in that case you really want LD_BIND_NOW -- it you need predictable performance and can't afford delay, then you can't afford it for rarely used symbols either.

Look at it from a pure performance perspective (e.g. for embedded systems). You know that some symbols are very rarely, or at all, used. You can make them load lazily and improve startup time. You know that some symbols are critical to have and are used all the time. Make them load immediately. The benefits of this kind of control seems to be very obvious for me. And be it only for very resource constraint devices.

Its not "Impossible" by patching the binary. It might be non trivial though.

From your application I guess you could use dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "function") for the rarely used or optional symbols, then internally cast that to a function pointer you use, instead of the bound-at-start mechanism?
In C/C++ it is relatively easy to declare your own stub function that call_once loads the symbol address and then performs the call or returns an error such as ENOTSUP or ENOSYS, or something that means the call legitimately failed so it can be completely transparent to the rest of the application. In a perfect world the compiler should tail-optimise your stub into a jump, reusing the stack and register arguments.
If you really needed it completely app-transparent you could have your own stub dynamic library that is all bound at start, but only partially binds to the real implementation.
More complex topologies are possible to hide the problem but they add startup time overhead.
